# How to download OpenCV on Anaconda?

Tags: python, macos, opencv

Can someone tell me where do I get the link to download OpenCV?

I use a `Mac` and none of these terminal commands work as the solving environment gets frozen:

```
    conda install -c conda-forge opencv conda install -c

    conda-forge/label/gcc7 opencv conda install -c   

    conda-forge/label/broken opencv conda install -c      

    conda-forge/label/cf201901 opencv conda install -c         

    conda-forge/label/cf202003 opencv
```

Comment: If you want to install opencv libraries via conda  then check this link for multiple versions https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/ ,or else use pip install opencv-python in your virtual environment

Comment: Try this `conda install -c menpo opencv3`